# Why was this question deleted by Community, after being closed but with score not below $0$?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, auto-delete

There was a question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987284/fuel-level-in-horizontal-cylindrical-tank/987290#987290

It was closed but wasn't downvoted below 0. So Why has it been deleted?

Comment: I have tagged this as ([meta-tag:specific-question]). If you want to discuss the general issue (i.e., when a question is auto-deleted) and this particular question was used merely as an example, feel free to remove the tag.

Comment: I don't see how this would a duplicate of that.  It is a question about how the autodeletion works, not a request for undeletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) gives the criteria for autodeletion, and this question met one of them.  Although one of the other criteria depends on the score being negative, the one for closed questions without upvoted or accepted answers, etc., only requires that the score be nonpositive.

Comment: I thought it was deleted by three 20k users. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user31782: For deletion by users, there is no requirement that the score be even nonpositive. Closed questions (i.e., past the "on hold" period) can be closed by the votes of 10k users even if they have positive score. [deleted and reposted to correct two homophone errors]

Comment: @JonasMeyer You wrote "can be closed" instead of "can be deleted". Also, the waiting period for deletion is 48 hours, while for [on hold]->[closed] it's five days. These are not related by software, but some users [prefer to wait](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16726/) until the [closed] stage.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii: Thank you.  The first point is another typo, the second I neglected to research, and although not technically incorrect, is potentially misleading.  I prefer to wait until [closed] stage anyway, but I appreciate the information and correction.